# What would cause jenkins or msbuild to not generate files and how can I fix it

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins setup with ms build and svn. I set Jenkins to archive artifacts `bin/Debug/*.*`. When I view the archive artifacts I cannot find my generated dll.

I looked in the work space folder but I cannot find anything generated. I looked in the file system but I can't find anything. where would this file be stored or what would delete this file and how can I stop it?

This is my console log

```
Building in workspace C:\Jenkins\jobs\XXXXX
Updating http://XXXXX at revision '2013-01-25T13:21:41.424 +0200'
U         Models\MultiViewContentInfo.cs
U         Models\ContentInfo.cs
At revision 1345
Archiving artifacts
Triggering a new build of XXXXXXX #24
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: you mean `bin/Debug` is empty?

Comment: Have you searched for the dll name in the console log?

Comment: yes my bin/debug is empty (well all it has is old files and not my dll that I expected it to generate). When I build in vs 2010 it creates it. I also checked bin/Release but that generates an error cos it's totally empty.

Comment: I don't see an actual build step in your console log. Just checkout and the archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. I didn't add a build step that was responsible for selecting a project file. 
i.e. 
Add Build step -> Build A visual studio project or solution using ms build
Enter msbuild version and msbuild file.